# How can I emulate my host system terminal on the browser?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, linux, terminal, process

#### Aim:

I am trying to use my Linux terminal from my web application.

#### Setup

- NodeJS
- ReactJS
- Ubuntu Server 20.04

#### Description

I want to create an application so that I can write commands in my browser, and NodeJS executed them on the backend and return the output.
Now, I know this is very simple using the spawn process, and I can `await response` and then send it back to the frontend, but I want it to be dynamic. The data is sent in real-time. So if the `apt install` command is being executed, I could see the stdout in real time on my browser window. How can I achieve it? Even if I use a web socket, how do I receive it from the terminal in real-time, because afaik, spawn process returns the output all at once.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://xtermjs.org/

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Danger Will Robinson!! Do not do this unless the goal is to have an extremely vulnerable machine

Comment: @leitning I believe that is the case. What do you suggest as an alternative? Because even AWS and Azure provide functionalities like these, so that means there must be a secure way.

Comment: What is the end goal and why isn't just normal SSH a valid option?

Comment: Okay, so I have a machine in my workspace and I want to provide access to VMs running through multipass on a server over the web because giving SSH access means giving access to the whole system, which I don't want to.